# Error when I run Univariate Survival Analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to run a univariate analysis. Here is my data:

```
library(survivalAnalysis)
AgeMRE <- c(60, 67, 71, 66, 71, 73, 50, 67, 67, 61)
OutcomeMRE <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
EventMRE <- c(NA,  3, NA,  2,  3, 12,  2,  6, NA, 11)
datasetMRE <- data.frame(cbind(AgeMRE, EventMRE, OutcomeMRE))
```

where:
Age is the age of the patient
Outcome is whether the patient experienced the primary outcome (1 - Yes, 0 - No)
Event is the time of the outcome experienced (numbers in months, if the Outcome is not experienced, the Event == NA)
Then I run the following code:

```
dataset = data.frame(datasetMRE)
dataset %>%
  analyse_survival(vars(EventMRE, AgeMRE), by = OutcomeMRE) -> 
  resultuni
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in survfit.formula(Surv(EventMRE, AgeMRE) ~ 1, data = data) : 
  data set has no non-missing observations
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In analyse_survival(., vars(EventMRE, AgeMRE), by = OutcomeMRE) :
  Survival analysis with factor OutcomeMRE: Only one factor value (1), no diffs possible.
2: In Surv(EventMRE, AgeMRE) : Invalid status value, converted to NA
```

In addition:
I want to check Age as a continuous variable but also as a group, like:

```
dataset = data.frame(datasetMRE)
dataset %>%
  analyse_survival(vars(EventMRE, ifelse(Age >=70, 1,0)), by = OutcomeMRE) -> 
  resultuni
```

How could I do that?

Comment: You miss the time component of the survival analysis!

Comment: The time is EventMRE in months.

Comment: In my knowledge time can't be `NA` since you are performing a time to event analysis there should be a time component from 1 to 12 or whatever, and in the simplest form an event column saying the an event occurred or not (0/1).

Comment: @ Arduan, As mentioned by Tarjae, you need a time component for all data. Not all subject will experience the event during the study period, this induces right-censored observations. For example, for survival data, the subjects that are still alive at the end of the study period should at least have the last sampling / observation date, with the status 'alive'. You can find more info there : [http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/survival-analysis]

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I encoded EventMRE to '13' if no outcome were observed. Still receiving an error:

```

Error in survfit.formula(Surv(EventMRE, AgeMRE) ~ OutcomeMRE, data = data) : 
  data set has no non-missing observations
In addition: Warning message:
In Surv(EventMRE, AgeMRE) : Invalid status value, converted to NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I used different package and manage to do it this way:

```
library("survival")
#Encoding Outcome 0 as EventMRE2 = 13
datasetMRE$EventMRE2 = ifelse(is.na(datasetMRE$EventMRE), 13, datasetMRE$EventMRE)

res.cox <- coxph(Surv(EventMRE, Outcome) ~ AgeMRE, data = datasetMRE)
summary(res.cox)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the package `survivalAnalysis` is just a tidyverse wrapper around package:survival functions. Appears to be a rather flimsy wrapper. The error code was reporting that `survfit.formula` (which is a function in the *survival* package) was not getting the right sorts of arguments,